# How to calculate distance traveled given 2D velocities?

Tags: calculus, integration

Given velocities in $x$ and $y$ directions, $V_x$ and $V_y$, why can’t  we integrate  these two velocities vs. time from $0$ to $t$ to find distances traveled in x and y directions respectively, and then use Pythogorean theroem to get total distance traveled? I found this approach gives different answers compared to integration of $\sqrt{V_x^2+V_y^2} $ vs time from $0$ to $t$. I must have missed something simple, what is it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What you are asking is if $\int \sqrt{f^2+g^2} = \sqrt{\left(\int f\right)^2+\left(\int g\right)^2}$? Do you think this will be true in general?

Comment: I am asking why LHS is correct and RHS is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By means of the first approach, you calculate the distance between the initial and the final points of the trajectory. On the other hand, with the second approach, what is calculated is the total *length* of the trajectory, which, in general (if the path followed is not a straight line) is greater than the distance between the initial and final points.

This is simple to see: with the first approach what you do is calculate the total displacement in both axes separately and that will only give you the final point of the trajectory, then use the Pythagorean theorem to get the distance from the original point to the final point. If, instead, you proceed as in the second method, you (heuristically) calculate the *instantaneous displacement* of the particle and then add it all up to get the length of the trajectory.